# Microsoft one note graph api doesn't include recently created pages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

The '/onenote/sections/{sectionId}/pages' endpoint doesn't return recently created pages. It used to work without issues. Since the past few days, it isn't returning newly created pages. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/{sectionId}/pages?top=100

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting this issue Ajay! It's being investigated and will let you know when fixed.

Comment: I'm subscribed to Microsoft One Drive and pay Microsoft every month mainly to store my Notes. I've created an app which heavily uses Microsoft graph's one note api. It would be great if you people could speed things up and fix this issues as I could see that many people have the same issue. :)

Comment: @manjusha Has there been any update on the Onenote MS Graph apis to return the new pages?